# GTK+3 OpenGL: OpenGL calls fails

Tags: opengl, gtk3

I have previously been using the GtkGL extension to render opengl embedded in gtk, and I thought I'd upgrade to GTK+3.16 and use the built in support.
I have unfortunately run into a snag that I can't figure out.

I can successfully initialize the GdkGLContext (I do this in the realize signal of my main window):

```
m_window = gtk_widget_get_window(widget);

GError* err = nullptr;
m_context = gdk_window_create_gl_context(m_window, &err);
ASSERT_FORMAT(m_context != nullptr, "Failed to create OpenGL context for editor window (%s)", err->message);

gdk_gl_context_set_required_version(m_context, 4, 5);

gboolean success = gdk_gl_context_realize(m_context, &err);
ASSERT_FORMAT(success == TRUE, "Failed to realize Editor GL context (%s)", err->message);

gdk_gl_context_make_current(m_context);

Logging::verbose("OpenGL Device: %s - %s.\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR), glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
Logging::verbose("Version supported: %s, %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION), glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
```

This seems to work, it's not giving any errors or glError, though as soon as I try to do any opengl calls they fail with "invalid enum":
(example: one of the first thing I do is glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE), which fails with "invalid enum"). And it eventually crashes when it can't create framebuffers or shaders.

My guess is that this is somehow caused by incorrect settings being used when creating the GdkWindow, but I can't really figure out what.
I printed some debug information about the GdkVisual and the OpenGL context:

```
Bits per RGB: 8. Byte order: LSB
Visual Type: GDK_VISUAL_TRUE_COLOR
OpenGL Device: NVIDIA Corporation - GeForce GTX 970/PCIe/SSE2.
Version supported: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42, 4.50 NVIDIA
```

(This is actually even a bit weirder, the opengl information comes from glGetString, so these opengl calls at least seem to work).

I have the same code running with a SDL window, and there it works fine.

I'm running GTK+3 version 3.18.9 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have also tried creating a GtkGLArea instead, but that gives the same issues.

My theory is that it has something to do with what parameters the OpenGL context is created with, since it worked previously with GtkGLExt, but not with GTK+3.16's GdkGLContext, but I can't figure out what parameter is wrong.

Comment: Which "any OpenGL calls" are you having problems with? Are you using an OpenGL loader before accessing OpenGL functions?

Comment: I'm using libepoxy to load gl symbol. But I think I have figured it out. GTK+3 loads opengl with core profile, and I have some parts of my program that is not core profile compliant, so it's actually only those calls that fails.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my issue was that my code wasn't OpenGL core profile compatible.
So if someone else run into similar issues: Make sure your OpenGL calls are following the core profile (ie VAO always bound, and some functions have been removed).